# Which executor and scheduler is getting used

Tags: java, spring-mvc, configuration, scheduler, executor

I was reading below article to implement executor and scheduler.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-enable-annotation-support

Can any one please tell me which executor and scheduler does it use when we specify below xml entry

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler"/>
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5"/>
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally spring uses `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` for namespace of `task:executor` and `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` for `task:scheduler`. 
Refer respective API docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have another question regarding scheduling cron job at runtime. I will post another question for it.

Answer (score -1):

specify the package

any classes inside that package which have the annotation @Configuration, @EnableScheduling and method with @Scheduled(cron="") will be scheduled on the mentioned time in the cron expression.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. YOu don't need `@EnableScheduling` as there is also the xml counterpart which is used here. The only thing necessary is the `@Scheduled` which is the trigger.

Comment: @M.Deinum, can you please tell me, which scheduler is used to invoke `@Scheduled` method?

Comment: You only have 1 scheduler which is used.

Comment: I mean which scheduler, because here it is mentioned as `myScheduler`.

Comment: As stated you only have 1 scheduler that is the one that is used.

Comment: @M.Deinum, sorry I think my question was incomplete. My question is which class is getting initialized (for eg ThreadPoolTaskScheduler) and then it runs scheduled job.

Comment: @NamanGala I mentioned the respective class names in my answer which is what I think you are looking for; if so please accept it for benefit of others. Thanks!